# Symfony httplug bundle handle missing EventSubscriberInterface

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

In a Symfony 5.1.8 project I updated the httplug bundle to version 1.19.0.

It is mentioned in the changelog:

> ConfiguredClientsStrategy no longer implements
> EventSubscriberInterface, this has been moved to
> ConfiguredClientsStrategyListener to avoid initializing the strategy
> on every request.

That results in an error in In

> EventDispatcher.php line 270

```
Failed to create closure from callable: class 'Http\HttplugBundle\Discovery\ConfiguredClientsStrategy' does not have a method 'onEvent'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue on Symfony 4.4.16, and I had to manually remove the old cache to fix it on production:

```
rm -rf var/cache/prod && bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: @user3440145 I think it is save to remove the cache folder, but on a system with huge traffic its is hard or even impossible to remove cache folder because system recreate files inside the deleting folder and cause rm fails to remove folder. I think it is better to rename the prod folder. so I used this command instead `mv var/cache/prod var/cache/_prod && rm -rf var/cache/_prod && bin/console cache:clear`